# Oracle Connection timed out timed out after publish .Net6 on Linux

Tags: linux, oracle, docker, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

My project is Asp.Net6 and using oracle database and publish on Linux; When no one don't use of my web application about several hours, and then the first one request to database I have connection timed out error from oracle.

**When client continuously using application don't connection time out.**

This is my error:

`Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-12570: Network Session: Unexpected packet read error ---> OracleInternal.Network.NetworkException (0x80004005): ORA-12570: Network Session: Unexpected packet read error ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (110): Connection timed out`

What should I do to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

That is because if the session was idle for some time, the connection would be terminated by firewall. My solution was to add

```
SQLNET.EXPIRE_TIME = 10
```

to sqlnet.ora file. This keeps connections alive by probing them in 10 minute intervals.

The Answer From: [sql*plus 11.2 client connection to oracle timing out on Linux](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/28574/sqlplus-11-2-client-connection-to-oracle-timing-out-on-linux)